# Remoção de string em script

Tags: string, linux, script, centos, sed

Para editar esse arquivo e retirar toda incidência de ^[[*m como eu edito o sed? As incidências estão marcadas em negrito.

> sed 's/\^[[*m//g' arquivo

A rotina de backup ainda está em execução no servidor!

```
The backup process began at 15:19:28 EDT and is currently on account **^[[1;33m0^[[0;00m** out of **^[[1;33m5** **^[[97m(0%)^[[0;00m**

Time since backups started: 00:00:05

Currently there are **^[[1;33m0^[[0;00m** accounts being excluded from backups.
To watch the log, use this command: **^[[97m**tail -f /usr/local/cpanel/logs/cpbackup/1497899968.log**^[[0;00m**

To check for backup duration history run: ^[[1;32m bash <(curl -ks scriptorigem) ^[[0;00m
```

Answer (score 2):

Aparentemente, as ocorrências que você quer filtrar são [sequências de escape ANSI](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%C3%B3digo_escape_ANSI).

Nesse caso, você pode usar um utilitário chamado [ansifilter](http://www.andre-simon.de/doku/ansifilter/en/ansifilter.php) para resolver seu problema:

```
$ ansifilter -i entrada.txt -o saida.txt
```

Alternativamente você pode usar o utilitário `sed` para remover as sequencias de escape `\x1b`:

```
$ sed 's/\x1b//g' entrada.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

com um comando só do sed dá pra remover todas as sequências de escape do terminal da seguinte forma:

```
sed 's/\^\[\[[^m]\+m//g' <seu_arquivo>
```

no sed, os caracteres que tem significado em Expressões Regulares precisam ser escapados (`^`, `[` e `+`).

Comment: Parece que esses caracteres apresentados na saída tem a ver com escape, como a resposta do Lacobus bem explicita.

Comment: São de fato sequencias de escape ANSI para os terminais como foi pelo @Lacobus. Eu apostaria que o sistema de backup que o OP citou esperava que essa saída fosse direcionada para um terminal (STDOUT ou STDERR) e não um arquivo.

Comment: pois é. Minha experiência é que acaba não sendo filtrado pelo texto que ele exibe, o texto que casa com sua regex, porém não tenho certeza